# Laravel Eloquent hasMany через больше чем 2 join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Я хочу получить сущность и связанные с ней данные. Есть таблицы А (таблица нужной мне сущности) и таблицы Б, В, Г, Д, где Д связана через все из этих таблиц с А.

Если использовать ORM то можно сделать так, но тогда данные будет не вложенными (объектA->Д->полеИзТаблицыД)

```
DB::connection()
 ->table('A')
 ->select('A.id', 'Д.очень_важное_поле')
 ->join('Б',  'Б.А_id', 'А.id')
 ->join('В',  'В.В_id', 'Б.id')
 ->join('Г',  'Г.Г_id', 'В.id')
 ->join('Д',  'Д.Д_id', 'Г.id')
 -get()
```

Вопрос такой, могу ли я описать через Eloquent Model эту связь так что бы потом сделать `A::with('Д')->all();`?

Answer (score 1):

Что насчет вложенных связей?

```
A::with('b.companies.persons.name')->get();

A::with(['b.companies.persons.name' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', '...');
}])->get();
```

Comment: А как описать такую связь в моделях? Каждая модель должна иметь описанную связь с другими моделями из приведенной цепочки таблиц?

Comment: @Bitrix24 да, в каждой модели пишете связь и по цепочке они все будут дергаться.